# live or living in some city

Tags: tense

> They <sub>.......................</sub> in Atlanta for more than ten years.

Should it be *live* or *living*?

Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 5):

Neither is idiomatic.

If they are still living in Atlanta, you should use *have lived* or *have been living*.

- The present perfect construction with *for TIMESPAN* and a stative verb is ordinarily a *continuative perfect*, signifying that the state described persists in the present.

If they live somewhere else now, you should use *lived*.

- The simple past with *for TIMESPAN* signifies that the state described ended at some time in the past.
- *Have lived* may work here, too, as an *existential perfect*, signifying that the past state described is a currently relevant episode in their history. However, additional information must be provided to distinguish this reading from the *continuative perfect*; for instance:

  > They have lived in Atlanta before, for ten years, so they should have many friends there.

For more about *continuative* and *existential* perfects, see [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32), especially [§3.2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32).

Answer (score 0):

Many possibilities but certainly not 'live' or 'living' I guess...

> They **have been living** in Atlanta for more than ten years. 
>   They **lived** in Atlanta for more than ten years. 
>   They **have lived** in Atlanta for more than ten years.

If you want 'living' to be used, it'll take *are*

> They *are living* in Atlanta for more than ten years.

Additionally, we use **for** to show a timespan (how many years) and use **since** to show a staring point (since 1990).